# Структура новостного приложения

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

Пишу приложение которое парсит сайт и отображает с него новости и прочую информацию. Для меня не совсем понятно **как грамотно передавать полученные данные в приложение** - например, создавать промежуточный JSON-файл или создавать массив объектов с данными вроде заголовков новостей, даты, путей к изображениям и тд (способ который использую я)?

Или есть другие варианты. Какой подход считается "best practice"?

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того что может предложить ваш источник данных. Если у сервиса есть апи, то можно использовать объекты которые соответствуют информации в json с ресурса. Вы создаете класс-модель и дальше уже после получения модели можете работать с методами класса. Я у себя в проекте, например, использовал [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) как библиотеку для работы с апи. Если же у сервиса нету апи, то придется парсить данные с сайта или где вы его можете посмотреть. Я думаю что `best practice` немного зависит от задачи которую пытаетесь решить, и как вариант в итоге может получится что-то свое, что будет работать лучше чем уже известные вам варианты. Но как мне кажется создание промежуточного файла немного усложняет логику вашего приложения: `обратится на сервер (получить данные) - сохранить данные в файл - проверить что файл нормально создался - вытащить данные из файла и конвертировать в объект - работать с объектом` я думаю в таком варианте можно спокойно получить на выходе объект после запроса. Плюс нужно будет файл потом удалить чтобы не засорять память. Конечно если речь идет о кешировании данных то конечно этот вариант имеет место быть :)

Comment: API  нет, использую SwiftSoup для парсинга.

Comment: то есть вы парсите сайт, правильно разбирая все элементы и вытаскивая то что вам нужно?

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли.

Comment: тогда как вариант - вытаскиваете поле -> ложите в поле класса -> потом юзаете класс

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.